# Is there a "reverse" for the stringer tool?

Tags: go

In go I can use `stringer` to convert const names to string:

```
//go:generate stringer -type=M
type M int

const (
    _ M = iota
    Foo // "Foo"
    Bar // "Bar"
)
```

Is there anything that would allow me to convert the `"foo"` string into a variable of type `M` except for a hand-written switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently discovered https://github.com/alvaroloes/enumer which adds a `TypeString(string) Type` method that will convert string value to type and can replace `stringer`.

Comment: It looks like `enumer` uses a map under the hood so it should perform better than a sequential search, too.

Answer (score 2):

Found one way of doing it but it's still half-manual. By using the mapping slice created by stringer it can also be searched for to reverse the operation:

```golang
type Measurement int

const (
    invalidMeasurement Measurement = iota
    Meters
    Liters
    Pounds
)

// Works with golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer
// v0.0.0-20200925191224-5d1fdd8fa346
func UnString(s string) Measurement {
    s = strings.ToLower(s)
    l := strings.ToLower(_Measurement_name)
    for i := 0; i < len(_Measurement_index)-1; i++ {
        if s == l[_Measurement_index[i]:_Measurement_index[i+1]] {
            return Measurement(i)
        }
    }
    // 
    return Measurement(0)
}
```

Comment: Looks like the indexing method must have changed between stringer versions. I updated the code accordingly (changed the index) and added the version identifier for what I'm using.

Comment: Also added example enum for context.